# Angular2 (ngSubmit) not working

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I've just started Angular2 and facing following error when add **(ngSubmit)** attribute to my form

```
Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("


    <form [ERROR ->]#form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
```

Following are some of my dependencies from package.json.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  }
```

I've following html form.

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="model.Title" #title="ngModel" name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="model.Description" #description="ngModel" class="summernote form-control" name="description" id="description"></textarea>
    </div>

</form>
```

And following **category.component** file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import { Category } from '../../../models/cms/Category';

@Component({
    selector: 'category',
    templateUrl: 'category.template.html'
})
export class CategoryComponent{

    model = new Category("dummyTitle","dummyDescription");

    onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.data);
    }   
}
```

Can someone please guide how to deal with this problem.

Comment: have you imported `FormsModule` in your App module file ?

Comment: @ranakrunal9 Thanks, Yes i have imported the FormsModel. But no gain

Answer (score 8):

you are missing a import file `import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';`

and you are using template Driven forms so you don't need FormBuilder.

try this way

**signup-form.component.html**

```
<form #signupForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="registerUser(signupForm)">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" ngModel>

  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ngModel>

  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

**signup-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'signup-form',
  templateUrl: 'app/signup-form.component.html',
})
export class SignupForm {
  registerUser(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, my `<button type="submit">Ok</button>` was outside form tag.
It must be inside form tag to work.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submitHandler()">

    <!-- ... form fields here ... -->

    <button type="submit">Ok</button> <!------- must be inside form -->
</form>
```

Comment: So easy to do, so hard to notice!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that button is inside the form and has type="submit". For example,

```
<ion-button type="submit"></ion-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind submit button outside of the form you have to give an id to the form and link this id to the button with form property and type submit:

```
<form id="myForm" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
...
</form>

<button form="myForm" type="submit"> 
  Submit Form 
</button>
```

Note: id doesn't have to be the same as formGroup name